# Decode IASI Satellite Spectrum - convert IDL to python

Tags: python, idl-programming-language

Since I have no experience in IDL coding, I need help converting the piece of code below to python.

The following parameters are known and are 1D arrays oder scalars.

```
IDefScaleSondNbScale, IDefScaleSondScaleFactor,
IDefScaleSondNsfirst, IDefScaleSondNslast,
IDefNsfirst
```

[image]

Comment: Um, that is not Matlab. Looks like Pascal. Guess you haven’t coded Matlab in a while :)

Comment: @mhopeng ha! thanks a lot :) I changed the title.

Comment: @mhopeng No, Pascal uses `:=` as the assignment operator. `=` is the equality relational operator. Besides that, semicolons `;` are required to separate statements.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Any guess what it is then? The “For-To-Do” is rare in my experience. Maybe it’s just pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's IDL and the python equivalent is the following:

```
SpectDecoded = np.empty_like(Spect, dtype=float)
for numScale in range(1, int(IDefScaleSondNbScale) + 1):
    SF = IDefScaleSondScaleFactor[numScale - 1]
    for chanNb in range(int(IDefScaleSondNsfirst[numScale - 1]), int(IDefScaleSondNslast[numScale - 1]) + 1):
        w = int(chanNb - IDefNsfirst[0])
        if w < SpectDecoded.shape[0]:
            SpectDecoded[w] = Spect[w] * 10 ** (-SF)
```